# 2d Human Pose Estimation evaluation metrics

Tags: computer-vision, vision

I am looking for any other metric used to evaluate 2d human pose.
What i have now is :

- Percentage of Correct Parts
- Percentage of Correct Key-points
- Percentage of Detected Joints
- Object Keypoint Similarity
- Mean Per Joint Position Error

I know there are object detection metrics like AP, AR, MOTP but i am specifically looking for human pose evaluation metrics like mentioned above.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for seeking more metrics?

Comment: Research ... Trying to find a better metric.

Comment: You might want to post this question at https://ai.stackexchange.com/ or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/  for some other perspectives.

Comment: okay.. will do that.. Thank you